Acronyms: No spacing, alignment and unwanted period at end
When using the glossaries package, I’m having trouble achieving the desired styling. I want to have a single tab of spacing between the acronym and its definition, and I also need to remove the period at the end of the definition. How can I adjust the package settings to meet these requirements?
The example code..
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[automake,nonumberlist,xindy,acronym]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}

% Define the acronyms
\newacronym{fea}{FEA}{Finite Element Analysis}
\newacronym{fem}{FEM}{Finite Element Method}
\newacronym{fe}{FE}{Finite Element}
\newacronym{noe}{NoE}{Number of Equations}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\def\sp{2cm}

\markboth{Acronyms}{Acronyms}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=list]

\newpage

\acrfull{fe}
\acrfull{fem}
\acrlong{fea}
\acrshort{noe}

\end{document}

..produces this result:

But what I really want is something like this (ignore the blue color, the bold first letters, and the slight misalignment):


This question covers the full stop.

The list style uses description and you can modify the appearance with the help of enumitem.
Adapt 4em to your liking. You can then use nopostdot to suppress the trailing period.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[automake,nonumberlist,xindy,acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Define the acronyms
\newacronym{fea}{FEA}{Finite Element Analysis}
\newacronym{fem}{FEM}{Finite Element Method}
\newacronym{fe}{FE}{Finite Element}
\newacronym{noe}{NoE}{Number of Equations}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlist[description,1]{labelwidth=4em}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=list,nopostdot]
\endgroup

\clearpage

\acrfull{fe}
\acrfull{fem}
\acrlong{fea}
\acrshort{noe}

\end{document}


If you do
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=list,nopostdot,nogroupskip]

you get

